# How to access "/" directory in macOS finder when sftp'ing to a server as the root user. Only able to access directories above /root/*

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, sftp, login

I have just upgraded an Ubuntu server and during the upgrade, I decided to keep all old versions of .conf files instead of replacing them with the upgraded package versions. Now, I have to go and manually merge the new files **(*.conf.dpkg-dist)** with the original files **(*.conf)**. My strategy to do so was to mount the servers root filesystem via SFTP on my local Mac and use a MacOS Gui Visual Diff merger tool like [Meld](https://meld.app) to merge the old files with the new files directly on MacOS.

This sounds great in concept, but the problem is, that when I SFTP into my server on my Mac, I am only able to navigate directory's above the login users home directory, preventing me from accessing any files or folder in `/` such as the `/etc` folder. In other words, if I sftp login as "my-non-root-user-with-sudo-privilages", I can only access `/home/my-non-root-user-with-sudo-privilages/*` directory and above. I cannot access just `/home` or `/etc`.

Same case goes if I log in as "root" with sftp. I can only see the `/root/*` directory and any directory/file above `/root/` but not below it. So again, logging in as "root" gives me access to everything in the `/root` folder and above, but I cannot go down to the `/` directory or navigate to the `/etc` directory even as root user.

My question is, (on macos) when SFTP logging into an Ubuntu Server as either "my-non-root-user-with-sudo-privilages" or "root", how can I navigate to restricted directories below the corresponding user's home folders, such as the `/etc` folder?

Answer (score 0):

That is how an [S]FTP server works. By default, an [S]FTP server will, when you log in as `user`, start you in `user`'s home directory, and that will be your root directory for the entire session. This is a security measure to keep random users from logging into FTP and snooping through your system.

You can create a custom FTP user who has access starting at `/`, but that has to be done server side, and I don't need to tell you that it's a security risk.

Comment: How exactly would i create a user on Ubuntu that starts at / on the server? It would only be temporary so im not worried about security.

Comment: That would depend on what FTP server you have on your Ubuntu machine. And I don't think you've given us that information.

Comment: im just using the sftp program that comes natively with openssh and is listed in sshd_config at the bottom. How do i figure out what that is?

Comment: sshd actually uses the Linux user list. So what you would do is create a new Linux user and set their home directory to `/`. Be sure that user is included in the `ssh` group so they have the permission they need.